# SwiftLint 'excluded' not working for one folder

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftlint

my swiftlint.yml file is not excluding my "Generated Mocks" folder. I've tried `Generated\ Mocks` and `'Generated Mocks'` Is there a solution to this?

```
excluded:
  - Pods
  - MyProjectTests
  - MyProject/Helpers/Constants.swift
  - Generated Mocks
```

edit: The Generated Mocks folder was generated from a dependency I added so I hope that helps

Comment: Try with double quotes or single quotes?

Comment: yes I have tried double quotes and single quotes

Comment: have you tried both quotes and escaping the space? `- "Generated\ Mocks"` ?

Comment: Just tried it no luck. The other files are working so strange this one isn't.

Comment: you can try to use array syntax `excluded: [Pods, ..., Generated Mocks]`. However, in YAML it should work without quotes. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes It is in the same folder directory as Pods which is working. I will try the array

Comment: I did a quick test in a project I am working on and I had no problem excluding a folder with a space in the name by just adding the folder name as it is

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of writing excluded commands in **swiftlint.yml** file, simply use **included** command and add your project path, tests etc. in here (paths where you want your swiftlint to run).

   For instance, my **swiftlint.yml** file looks like this:

> ```
> included:
>  - [PROJECT_NAME]
>  - [PROJECT_NAME]Tests
>  - [PROJECT_NAME]UITests
> ```

I only have a **included** command and I added paths where I want my swiftlint rules to work.

2. Make sure to add this command:

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
swiftlint --config [PROJECT_PATH]/.swiftlint.yml
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

to:

> Target > Build Phases > Run Script

3. And lastly, make sure that your **.swiftlint.yml** file is located of your project's root path.

Build the project, you'll see that your SwiftLint warnings will show only for your included folders & files.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to change the destination folder name from Genera†ed Mocks to GeneratedMocks, and then use this in .yaml (works for me):

```
excluded:
- Pods
- UnitTests/generated/GeneratedMocks.swift
```